# subprocess.run: Is it safe to combine check=True with stdout=PIPE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.5

Python 3.5 introduced the [`run()` function in the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) as the new recommended high-level means of subprocess invocation.

Amongst the three older (available [since Python 2.5 / 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)) high-level API functions is `check_call()`. The [Python 3.5 documentation claims](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) that `check_call()`

> [...] is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> run(..., check=True)
> ```

The documentation also warns against passing `subprocess.PIPE` as `stdout` or `stderr` to `check_call()`:

> #### Note
>
> Do not use `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` with this function. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.

As it's "equivalent", does this warning also apply to `run(..., check=True)`, i.e., should

```
subprocess.run(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)
```

and

```
subprocess.run(..., stderr=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)
```

be avoided, too? (The [documentation of `run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) doesn't mention this caveat.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it safe to combine check=True with stdout=PIPE?

**Yes.**

The reason one should not use `stdout=PIPE` as an argument to `subprocess.check_call` (or `subprocess.call`) is that those utility functions do not handle any input and output the processes may recieve/produce. If you wish to handle output, you needed (before `subprocess.run` was implemented) to use `subprocess.check_output`, which does specifically handle output, which, in [its own documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), states equivalence to `run(..., check=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout`. That clearly shows that `subprocess.run(...,check=True,stdout=PIPE)` is valid.